# crystal report 8.5 how to group using two fields at one level

Tags: crystal-reports, reporting, grouping

I have invoice table and have rows i.e. ST% and CST% and Tax where ST and CST represent Tax percent and the Tax field shows the value, Now while creating a report in Crystal **need to have grouping of CST and ST and also summary** of both like

```
toal CST 2% 
toal CST 4% 
toal ST 2% 
toal ST 4%
```

Can u help me out this using crystal report.
I am stuck with this.... this would be a great help
thanks in advance

Comment: your requirement is not clear.. you want to group or you want the data in the mentioned format?

Comment: Perhaps if you show a table of what your records look like and show what you want your results to be, the question will be more clear. 

If I understand your question correctly, you can group your records using a custom definition: http://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/scn/index?rid=/library/uuid/904e0155-5f2e-2e10-3c93-b8355f8e6650&overridelayout=true

Answer (score 0):

Create a formula , which combines the 2 fields and use it for the grouping. Is this not supported in 8.5 ?

Comment: Thanks. that's i have done but I need a Sepreate figures at the end of report as these are all from the same field . As i mentioned above. Is there any way to do that in 8.5